# Outlook 2010 disable/remove junk button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, ms-office, outlook-2010

Is there a way that I can disable/remove the junk button from Outlook?  We have an add-in that was installed that provides its own Junk button, but we don't want the users confused.  The 3rd party software does not have an option to remove/disable Outlook's built-in button.

I've posted it here with hopes of being able to do it via a c# add-in that handles other company-specific controls.  If this is not possible, I can repost over on SuperUser.

Thanks

Comment: nevermind...registry setting/group policy.  disables it.  that should handle it fine.